# How do I type a text in current focus without locator?

Tags: karate

I have a iframe to deal with which i cant do switchframe due to poor design.
I was able to use kay.TAB to get focus on text area within iframe when i want to enter the text.

How can I enter/type a text in current focused area without using any locator?

Answer (score 0):

Probably impossible. Try using `body` (or the iframe by CSS if possible) as the locator.

```
* input('body', 'your text')
```

If that doesn't work, you can experiment with Karate Robot, but you are on your own, or you can contribute your learnings and code perhaps: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-robot